# Use importhtml to import a single cell vs a whole column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importhtml

As the title would read, I am looking for a method to import data from a retail site to my current spreadsheet to have the prices update in real time. Unfortunately I am not educated in this so I am attempting to learn.

In my internet search I was able to come up with this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/darksteel/echoing-truth?xid=pid0b5fc15-f2ac-4f33-ae86-a3ed6d38bb44","table",2),"select Col2")
```

This although is returning 2 cells from the table that I was able to locate but I want to be able to just import a single cell. In this case, just the normal price (first row).

Answer (score 1):

You can **wrap your current formula with the [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) function**:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/darksteel/echoing-truth?xid=pid0b5fc15-f2ac-4f33-ae86-a3ed6d38bb44","table",2),"select Col2"),1)
```

Using `=INDEX(...,1)` you get the first row, while using `=INDEX(...,2)` the second.

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we could try finding out why. If yes, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

The site I was using

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.discogs.com/Alex-K-Ultimate-NRG-4/release/2328156","table",2),"select Col3"),1)
```

There was no index.